# Connect to LDAPS using python-ldap

Tags: python, active-directory

I try to use module python-ldap to talk to ldaps server. But I fail to authenticate with the server. I have the both cer and keystore supplied and they both working on other applications for authentication. Below it's the code:

```
class LdapParser:
    # initialize ldap object and start connection
    def __init__(self, dn, pwd):
        try:
            ldap.set_option(ldap.OPT_X_TLS_CERTFILE, 'C:\\TLSCert\\mycert\\test.cer')
            ldap.set_option(ldap.OPT_X_TLS_CACERTFILE, 'C:\\TLSCert\\mykeystore\\cacerts')
            self.con = ldap.initialize('ldaps://172.34.21.111:636')
            self.con.simple_bind_s(dn,pwd)
            self.hostname = ""
            self.fieldname = "" # This will be category for hosts
        except Exception as e:
            raise e
```

Below is the error I got (LDAP server is up and running):

> ldap.SERVER_DOWN: {'info': 'No such file or directory', 'errno': 2,
>   'desc': "Can't contact LDAP server"}